# How to ensure full package install after removing a meta-package?

Tags: package-management

Suppose I have a meta-package "m" that installs a, b, and c.  After doing an apt-get install m, I encounter an error during the install of b. In our example b does some compilation stuff.
Now I want to clean out m, a, b, and c and re-install.  What I want is for b to do its compilation stuff as well.
What I am seeing, though, is it just goes through the apt-get install routine very quickly, almost like working from a cache.

What is the best method to start from scratch after a meta-package uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to know how to rollback to the initial status after a failing installation of a metapackage.

Metapackages have the characteristic that the packages their bring in as recommended dependencies are not marked as *automatic*, so that do not get removed with an *autoremove* command when the metapackage itself is removed.

You could try to change this behaviour playing with the `APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections` option. Probably something like this should work

```
sudo apt-get -o APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections="" my-metapackage
```

If this worked, removing the metapackage and a following autoremove will bring to the initial situation.

**Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work:**, despite the option, all dependencies are **not** marked as automatic.

Comment: Is the only real option to run a command to see what is *actually* getting installed, e.g., a,b, and c in my example, and do a reset/reinstall from there?